# Uniformly convergence of series on compact set

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Prove that the series summation 
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}
$$
converges uniformly on compact sets.

I am struggling on this problem in complex analysis. I just know uniformly convergence of real series but totally unfamiliar with complex series. How to get start ?

Comment: By differentiating the natural logarithm of Euler's infinite product expression for the sine function $($ see [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) $)$, we get $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{z-n}~=~\pi~\cot\pi z,~$ which, when further differentiated with regard to *z*, yields $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(z-n)^2}~=~\pi^2~\csc^2\pi z.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Weierstrass $M$-test works also for complex series. Fix a compact set $K$. If $z \in K$ and $|n|$ is large enough, the denominator doesn't vanish on $K$. Estimate the supremum norm of
$$
\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}
$$
for large $n$ on $K$. (Note that the sum isn't defined for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: Then what will be supremum of that?